# How to improve the ECS Renderer System v2 for instantiating 50.000 capsules in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I instantiate 50.000 capsules with ~30fps. I do not have any systems which are calculating anything (just have a spawn system for the beginning). 
My problem is the renderer system v2 in the entity debugger. Is there a way to improve the performance for holding 50.000 capsules? On my 4 core laptop I get these 30fps, on my main pc I get ~60-70fps (8 core, better GPU).

Is there a way to improve the renderer performance? I use GPU instancing, burst and a prefab for instantiating (Convert a Prefab Gameobject Capsule to an entity and copying this entitiy 49.999 times. Will there be a better performance if I create the entity from scratch? I dont think so.. I just search for a way to improve my renderer system which holds the 50.000 capsules.
I read something about culling but this would not help if I focus all 50.000 entitiys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
For a better performance just use the Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Diffuse Shader. Enable GPU Instancing.